# Find equation of curve fit programmatically in Matlab?

Tags: statistics, math-software, matlab, regression

In MATLAB, when you plot something, there's a tool available which is called "curve fitting". And if you have a set of data points and a linear correlation, this tool will easily come up with an equation on the form y = ax + c.

I want to do exactly that, but I need to do it programmatically. I know that I can use `polyfit` to find the coefficient, and `polyval` to evaluate as many data points as I want, but what I can't figure out is how to find the constant c. This is very important, since I need to be able to plot the line as well next to my data points.

Thank you.

Comment: Use the equations [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to give two answers.

---

Answer 1: If you already know $a$, then $c = \bar{y} - a\bar{x}$, where $\bar{x}$ and $\bar{y}$ are the means of the $x$ and $y$ values, respectively.  (This is actually in that pile of formulas in the link provided by Yuval Filmus.)

---

Answer 2: At least in my version of Matlab, polyfit gives both $a$ and $c$.  For example, if you generate a set of data via (I'm modifying the example given in the Matlab help)

```
x = (0: 0.1: 2.5)';
y = erf(x);
```

and then call polyfit with $n=1$ (for a linear curve fit, or linear regression)

```
p = polyfit(x,y,1)
```

The output is

```
0.3554    0.3191
```

which means your linear equation is $y = 0.3554x + 0.3191$.

Comment: You are right. I said constant, instead of coefficient, and in my mind there was no doubt that polyfit would not give me the constant. So I can see that I confused you. Polyfit DOES find the constant, even in my version of Matlab. It now works!